# roslaunch <machine> tag - custom ssh port

Tags: roslaunch, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

is there currently any way to specify a custom ssh port on a remote  target? I tried to specify an alias (from .ssh/config) and address="fqdn:port" but none works (cannot resolve host address for machine:port (or ALIAS)).

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32573/roslaunch-%3Cmachine%3E-tag---custom-ssh-port/) by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2012-04-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-04-25**:
...out of curiosity, why do you need a custom ssh port? I can't (off the top of my head) think of why you'd need one.

**Comment by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on 2012-04-25**:
well I would like to use 22, but the external partner only provides access at a custom port... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch should take into account your ssh configuration file.
If this is not the case, please comment on [this ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3158).

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on 2012-04-25**:
Thanks for pointing out that ticket. I'll try to debug my problem!